# 6x tabs each tab has an accordion - I can't see how to set up seperate IDs for the Accordions to work?

Tags: jquery

Hello What Im trying to do is : I have a tab bar with 6 tabs. Inside each tab I want to place an accordion and or a slider. The problem is I can get 1x tab to behave, where it has a slider or accordion and they work fine. When I set up the next tab the tab won't load the accordion or slider and or if it does the accordion or slider fails or mirrors the first slider or accordion.

Im certain its about creating different ID's for each accordion and Slider to behave independently in each tab. I don't see how to do this, what Im doing wrong.

Im knew to this arena of knowledge, so not sure what to post in terms of code etc.

So I placed the html :

There is a jQuery file :

The CSS I didn't think would effect the outcome of the missing ID for the Accordion

I Hope this is correct.

(function($, window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';

```
// init cubeportfolio
$('#js-grid-faq').cubeportfolio({
    filters: '#js-filters-faq',
    defaultFilter: '*',
    animationType: 'sequentially',
    gridAdjustment: 'default',
    displayType: 'default',
    caption: 'expand',
    gapHorizontal: 0,
    gapVertical: 0
});
```

})(jQuery, window, document);

```
    <section class="main-contain dip-style bg-gray">
            <div class="container">  
                    <div class="login-area mb30">
                <div class="login-header">
                            <div class="login-details">
                                <ul class="nav nav-tabs navbar-right">
                                    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#description">Description</a></li>
                                    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#size">Size</a></li>
                                      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#test-1">Test-1</a></li>
                                      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#test-2">Test-2</a></li>
                                      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#test-3">Test-3</a></li>
                                      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#test-4">Test-4</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                <div class="tab-content">
             <!-- Description -->
            <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="description">
                        <p>  <!-- ACCORDIAN START --> <!-- ACCORDIAN START --> <!-- ACCORDIAN START --> <!-- ACCORDIAN START --> <!-- ACCORDIAN START -->

        <section class="main-contain bg-gray">
            <div class="container">
<div id="js-filters-faq" class="cbp-l-filters-underline">
    <div data-filter="*" class="cbp-filter-item-active cbp-filter-item">
        All
    </div>
    <div data-filter=".buying" class="cbp-filter-item">
        Buying
    </div>
    <div data-filter=".author" class="cbp-filter-item">
        Author
    </div>
    <div data-filter=".account" class="cbp-filter-item">
        Account
    </div>
    <div data-filter=".copyright" class="cbp-filter-item">
        Copyright
    </div>
    <div data-filter=".community" class="cbp-filter-item">
        Community
    </div>
</div>

<div id="js-grid-faq" class="cbp cbp-l-grid-faq">
    <div class="cbp-item buying">
        <div class="cbp-caption">
            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">

                Where can I find my Purchase Code?
            </div>
            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                    Every item purchased on Envato Market has a unique code, called a purchase code.
                    <br>
                    A purchase code is used by authors to verify you have purchased a licence for the item. The purchase code may be required to access an author’s support site (if support is offered) or to enable automatic updates.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cbp-item community">
        <div class="cbp-caption">
            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">

                Forum Comments by Envato Staff & Moderators
            </div>
            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                    Envato is extremely fortunate to have a huge community with highly engaged users. Part of our community’s time on Envato Market is spent within our forums, our common grounds for communication. In order to clarify the different roles and responsibilities of the various people and roles that post in our forums we hope you find the following information useful.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cbp-item community">
        <div class="cbp-caption">
            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">

                Forum and Community Rules
            </div>
            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                    Envato takes great pride in it’s global and thriving community! They're part of what makes the Envato Market sites fun and friendly. The forum rules and guidelines focus on mutual respect.
                    <br>
                    All users who wish to participate or give feedback are invited to do so.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

            </div>
        </section>

                      </div>
            <!-- End Description -->
```

```
        <section class="main-contain bg-gray">
            <div class="container">
<div id="js-filters-faq" class="cbp-l-filters-underline">
    <div data-filter="*" class="cbp-filter-item-active cbp-filter-item">
        All
    </div>
    <div data-filter=".buying" class="cbp-filter-item">
        Buying
    </div>
    <div data-filter=".author" class="cbp-filter-item">
        Author
    </div>
    <div data-filter=".account" class="cbp-filter-item">
        Account
    </div>
    <div data-filter=".copyright" class="cbp-filter-item">
        Copyright
    </div>
    <div data-filter=".community" class="cbp-filter-item">
        Community
    </div>
</div>

<div id="js-grid-faq" class="cbp cbp-l-grid-faq">
    <div class="cbp-item buying">
        <div class="cbp-caption">
            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">

                Where can I find my Purchase Code?
            </div>
            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                    Every item purchased on Envato Market has a unique code, called a purchase code.
                    <br>
                    A purchase code is used by authors to verify you have purchased a licence for the item. The purchase code may be required to access an author’s support site (if support is offered) or to enable automatic updates.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cbp-item community">
        <div class="cbp-caption">
            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">

                Forum Comments by Envato Staff & Moderators
            </div>
            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                    Envato is extremely fortunate to have a huge community with highly engaged users. Part of our community’s time on Envato Market is spent within our forums, our common grounds for communication. In order to clarify the different roles and responsibilities of the various people and roles that post in our forums we hope you find the following information useful.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cbp-item community">
        <div class="cbp-caption">
            <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">

                Forum and Community Rules
            </div>
            <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap">
                <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                    Envato takes great pride in it’s global and thriving community! They're part of what makes the Envato Market sites fun and friendly. The forum rules and guidelines focus on mutual respect.
                    <br>
                    All users who wish to participate or give feedback are invited to do so.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

            </div>
        </section>
```

```
            <!-- Description -->
            <div class="tab-pane media-block" id="test-1">
                <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="video-block">
                                    <iframe width="540" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Vpg9yizPP_g" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="video-block">
                                    <iframe width="540" height="360" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Vpg9yizPP_g" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                                </div>
                            </div>     
                </div>
            <!-- End Description -->
            </div>




              <!-- Size -->
            <div id="size" class="tab-pane">
            16" waist
            <br>
            34" inseam
            <br>
            10.5" front rise
            <br>
            8.5" knee
            <br>
            7.5" leg opening
            <br>
            <br>
            Measurements taken from size 30
            <br>
            Model wears size 31. Model is 6'2 
            </div>
           <!-- Size -->

            <!-- Description -->
            <div class="tab-pane media-block" id="test-2">
                <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                 <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img src="img/imac2.png" alt="" width="570" height="500" class="img-responsive">
                  </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img src="img/team1.jpg" alt="" width="263" height="263" class="img-responsive">
                  </div>
                            </div>     
                </div>
            <!-- End Description -->
            </div>

              <!-- Description -->
            <div class="tab-pane media-block" id="test-3">
                <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                                 <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img src="img/imac2.png" alt="" width="570" height="500" class="img-responsive">
                  </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img src="img/imac2.png" alt="" width="570" height="500" class="img-responsive">
                  </div>
                            </div>     
                </div>
            <!-- End Description -->


            </div>
            </div>
           </div>
         </div>  
        </section>
```

Comment: You cannot have duplicate id, I am seeing id=“js-grid-faq” multiple times. In your jquery code you can target multiple id like $(‘#js-grid-faq1, #js-grid-faq2).cuberportfolio({...

Comment: what is your expected behavior of the accordions? Close the rest if one is open? It's not immediately clear to me what the behavior should be.

Comment: Hello Joel Thank you for the reply.... What I want to do is : I have a tab menu bar, in each tab I want an accordion that holds unique information and all of these accordions must work independently. I can't see how to make the accordions work independently, I assumed I had to use a unique ID ...bestinamr offers the code $(‘#js-grid-faq1, #js-grid-faq2).cuberportfolio({     I'll certainly try this.

Comment: Hello Bestinamir  Hey thanks for the tip, I'll give it a try. Many thanks.